# VB.Net Website project returning errors which are not errors when I try to build it in vs2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I made some changes to a VB.Net website project in Visual Studio 2019, and then I merged them into the UAT project in TFS, so that they can be published to our UAT site. When I try to build the project the Error List contains one item stating:

> Maximum number of errors has been exceeded.

When I look at the Output tab I can see a long list of errors, but when I investigate them they are not errors at all. Some of the messages indicate syntax errors, but when I view the code nothing is highlighted and it all looks fine. Some of them say that a variable has not been declared, but it has. I also get Character is not valid errors - but again nothing is highlighted.

I should say that none of these errors is in any of the files I have been working on so they should be the same as the code which works fine on the UAT site. I already tried deleting the .vs folder and removing related folders from the Temporary ASP.Net Files folder, which fixed some issues I was having earlier, but not these errors.

I don't want to rant, but I feel like if Microsoft had a better testing regime there would be less of these sorts of issues and developers wouldn't need to waste so much time trying to work around their mistakes. I'm completely stuck at the moment so any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: It sounds like there is something very wrong in your project. It has nothing to do with Visual Studio itself so there is no reason to blame the that. How did you merge the website project to the other project? Something there went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could say I know how to fix this but I don't. All I know is after a mixture of visual studio restarts, failed publishes, and a couple of fixed references the project now compiles and even publishes.

That would've been a lot easier and less stressful if visual studio provided more accurate error messages

Comment: Most likely it was the "fixed references" that solved your issue.